# Keep data when orientation changed in Fragment class

Tags: android, orientation

I'm making Android Jabber chat client for school's work.

Everything works okay so far. But when I change the phone's orientation it will re-connect to server.

It only took 3-5 seconds to re-connect, but during that time if I send a message, it will cause `NullPointerException` which is the `XMPPConnection` variable.

By googling, I found that I can use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` but my `ChatClient` class extends `Fragment` and it's not available.

My target is 4.0.3+ so I don't need to worry about compatibility support or such.

Any solution except using `static` variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that hosting your xmppconnection inside the fragment is a good idea.

A common approach would be to host it inside a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) so your connection can persist even if the application is in background (and in any case does not depend on your activity / fragment recreation), or, if you are not interested in having it connected when your app is in background, another good option would be to have the xmppconnection hosted inside a singleton object.

If, on the other hand, this is a school project and all you want is the fragment persist along configuration changes such as rotation, you can use 
[setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) method:

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `Service` looks good. But do I need to start from beginning? For now I have two classes: ChatClient which extends `Fragment` and implements `PacketListener`, then ChatConnection which extends `AsyncTask` to request connection.

Comment: That's why I wrote about setRetainInstance. It would mean to rewrite the interface with xmpp in a way that can be contained in a service. Another thing I would worry about if it was a real world project is if the xmppconnection is handled in the ui thread or if the library you are using is implemented in its own thread.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use `Service`.

Comment: Keep also in mind that if you are using a service, the connection will be kept running even if your user exits from your application. A good practice is (at least) to warn him with a notification icon that the service is still in background.